# How to check greater value in javascript?

Tags: javascript

There is two value 'a' and 'b'. i need to check a is greater than 'b'

if it is a big value its check the greater values. but here difference only in point values. it ignore point values

```
var a='20.796';
var b='20.190';
if (parseInt(a) > parseInt(b))
 {
alert("function can work");
return false;
}
```

Comment: Why are you defining them as Strings if you want to compare them numerically anyway?

Comment: Try using `parseFloat` instead

Comment: Use `if (parseFloat(a) > parseFloat(b))` ... that would work fine for your particular case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's ignoring point values because you are parsing them as integers in the if statement conditional. You have a couple options.

1. Define the variables as floats instead of strings; remove the parseInt function calls.
2. Exchange the [parseInt](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp) for [parseFloat](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parsefloat.asp) calls.

Answer (score 1):

You parse your numbers as [integers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer). You want rational/real numbers instead. Use [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat):

```
var a = '20.796';
var b = '20.190';
console.log(parseInt(a,10),parseInt(b,10));
console.log(parseFloat(a),parseFloat(b));
```

Result:

```
20 20
20.769 20.190
```

Also, please always use the `radix` argument if you use [`parseInt(string [, radix])`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).

Furthermore - if `a` and `b` are numbers, don't save their values in a string. It's much easier to save their values instead:

```
var a = 20.796;
var b = 20.190;
```

Answer (score 0):

Define your numbers as numbers, and remove the call to parseInt or use parseFloat.

```
var a=20.796;
var b=20.190;
if (a > b)
{
    alert("function can work");
    return false;
}
```

or

```
if (parseFloat(a) > parseFloat(b))
{
    alert("function can work");
    return false;
}
```

Comment: `parseFloat()` does not take a second parameter; no radix is really needed.

Comment: @KarimSaNet That's what copy > paste will get ya. Lol. Indeed, parseFloat only takes one param.

Answer (score 0):

Here, your solution is to parse the strings as floating points rather than integers. For example:

```
var a = '20.796',
    b = '20.190';
if (parseFloat(a) > parseFloat(b)) {
    // TODO: .. code ..
}
```

Your code right now is parsing the strings as integers. Integers are whole number values and CANNOT contain a decimal value, meanwhile floats or floating point numbers CAN contain a decimal value. When you call 'parseInt()' on the floating point, it truncates (or removes) the decimal value and just keeps the whole value. Which is obviously not what you're looking for.

PS: I'm guessing you're new to JavaScript, and so I just want to wish you good luck with learning it. Personnaly, I find JavaScript to be a very beautiful language if you learn it well.